# Missing Return stataement error in If else If block in Java?

Tags: java

why is this giving me a missing return statement error? I have written return statement in every block. What can be the issue?

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> rootToNodePath(Node root,int elem){
      if(root == null){
          return null;
      }
      if(elem < root.data){
        ArrayList<Integer> out1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        out1 = rootToNodePath(root.left,elem);
        if(out1 != null){
            out1.add(root.data);
            return out1;   //returned here
        }
      }
      else if(elem > root.data){
        ArrayList<Integer> out2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        out2 = rootToNodePath(root.right,elem);
        if(out2 != null){
            out2.add(root.data);
            return out2;  //returned here
        }
      }
      else{
         ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         output.add(root.data);
         return output; // returned here as well
      }
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of your last `else` and just have it normal and return. should get rid of the error

Comment: What if `if(elem < root.data)` is true, but inner `if(out1 != null)` is false?

Comment: You did not cover all the cases, in some of them you have no return statement. Anyway bad idea to put return every where in your method. Finish your method with return result; and replace in your code return xxx by result=xxx

Comment: where am I supposed to go if I have doubts? people downvoting my question' I was genuinely stuck and needed help

Answer (score 1):

You have not added a return statement in outer ifs and hence the error.

For example there is no return if `out1==null`. Your `if(elem < root.data)` shoud have a return statement which is executed in all cases.

```
if(elem < root.data){
        ArrayList<Integer> out1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        out1 = rootToNodePath(root.left,elem);
        if(out1 != null){
            out1.add(root.data);
            return out1;   //returned here
           // WHAT IF PROGRAM DOESN'T GO HERE??
        }
      }
```

You must either add a *return* in *else* block for `if(out1 != null)`. OR, add a default return to `if(elem < ròot.data)`

Same is TRUE for other code blocks too in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that any case the code returns something. Theoretically your code could not get into the if/else statements and therefore gets to the end of the method without returning anything. You have to put an additional `return` statement at the end of the method (after the last else).

Somethig like this might work:

```java
    public static ArrayList<Integer> rootToNodePath(Node root,int elem){
        if(root == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(elem < root.data){
          ArrayList<Integer> out1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          out1 = rootToNodePath(root.left,elem);
          if(out1 != null){
              out1.add(root.data);
              return out1;   //returned here
          }
        }
        else if(elem > root.data){
          ArrayList<Integer> out2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          out2 = rootToNodePath(root.right,elem);
          if(out2 != null){
              out2.add(root.data);
              return out2;  //returned here
          }
        }

       ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       output.add(root.data);
       return output;

   }
```

Also you might not want to return null if the first condition is met:

```java
if(root == null){
    return null;
}
```

It is better to return an empty `ArrayList`, so the code that is calling your method does not have to check for a `null` condition:

```java
if(root == null){
    return new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For all the conditions you have given the return statement but there is no return statement other than the condition you have given. That's why the compiler is asking for one return statement for the default behavior.